# On the board there are numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> On the board the numbers $2$, $\sqrt 2$, $\sqrt{3/5}$, $1/3$ are written. Andy will play a game, where each step follows the following sequence:
>
> 1. Andy chooses two numbers on the board, for example $a$ and $b$, which fulfill the condition $ab > 1$.
> 2. The two selected numbers are deleted, then write two new numbers on the board, namely $a - 1/b$ and $b + 1/a$.
>
> If in any condition the steps above cannot be carried out, then the game is stopped. Is it possible for the game to stop with the numbers written on the board being 1, 1, 1, 1?

The attempt I conducted involved starting with the numbers $2$ and $\sqrt 2$. I tried to find a pattern by multiplying them continuously, but I did not see any consistent pattern; instead, the numbers became irrational. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hints: 1/ Show that the terms are always positive. 2/ Find a mono-variance, which indicates that we can't get to 1, 1, 1, 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider any four arbitrary positive numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$. The product $P$ of these numbers is

$$P = \alpha \beta \gamma \delta$$

Suppose two arbitrary positive numbers $m,n \in \{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta\}$ are subjected to the described operation, and suppose $\{x, y\} \equiv \{\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta\} - \{m,n\}$.
The new numbers thus obtained are:
$m' = m-\frac{1}{n}$ and $n' = n+\frac{1}{m}$.

The new product thus becomes $P' = (m-\frac{1}{n}) (n+\frac{1}{m}) x y = (mn-\frac{1}{mn}) x y$.
Notice that since all the four numbers are positive, $mn>0$ and thus $(1/mn)>0$. Therefore,

$$P' = (mn-\frac{1}{mn}) x y < m n x y = \alpha \beta \gamma \delta = P$$

This implies that the operation described always decreases the product of the four numbers after each iteration.
The four numbers given are $2, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$. Thus the initial product is:

$$2×\sqrt{2}×\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}×1/3 = \sqrt{\frac{8}{15}} < 1$$

Since any number of iterations of the operation must always decrease the product, the product after any number of iterations must be $< \sqrt{\frac{8}{15}} < 1$. Thus, a product of $1$ is not attainable via this procedure, implying that the game can NOT stop at $1,1,1,1$.

Comment: Thank you Dominique for the edit. I'm seriously lacking in terms of LaTeX skills 

Comment: Me too about a year ago :-)

Comment: Can you suggest some sources where I might learn LaTeX?

Comment: Oh sorry, I used it for writing my thesis, but that's over twenty-five years now. In fact, I'm regularly here on the site, correcting people's posts, and when I need a symbol I don't know yet, I just google "LaTeX symboldescription", which generally gives a good result. Like this, bit by bit, I upgrade my LaTeX knowledge.

Comment: I'm also trying to learn tex to write some papers. No easy ways out of this huh? Lol. Thank you nonetheless!